# Is there any way to universally affect all doctrine queries in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a around 30 entities and all querying the database.
Now i want that i should only get those records where i have `ACTIVE = 1`. My all tables have that field.

One way is to change all the queries i am using.

Is there any other alternative where i can just grab the query before executing and add the `where clause` from single function like any `Listener or event`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. It's called a "filter" -- you can activate and deactivate them as needed. See the manual here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html.

You can configure them in Symfony2 using a  "filters" node under the doctrine node in your config file. Each filter should have two subnodes: "class" and "enabled" (enabled should, of course; be true, and class should be an FQCN pointing towards the filter).